# Can we do real http call in karma test?

Tags: karma-jasmine

I am trying to write an integration test using karma. I need to do real http call and get the actual response. I tried all solutions mentioned in #1434 like using passthrough() and commenting "$httpBackend: angular.mock.$HttpBackendProvider," in angular-mocks.js and none of them worked.

Here is my test code :

```
use strict';

describe('module: main, service: AuthService', function () {
beforeEach(module('ngMockE2E'));
// load the service's module
beforeEach(module('main'));
// load all the templates to prevent unexpected $http requests from ui-router
beforeEach(module('ngHtml2Js'));

// instantiate service
var AuthService;
var $q;
var deferred;
var $rootScope;

var response;

var scope, http, flush, httpBackend;

beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend,AuthService,$q, $rootScope) {
httpBackend = $httpBackend;

AuthService = AuthService;
$q = $q;
$rootScope = $rootScope;
deferred = $q.defer();

scope = $rootScope.$new();
}));

it('should do something', function () {
expect(!!AuthService).toBe(true);
expect(AuthService).not.toBeNull();

});

it('verify authenticating user', function () {
AuthService.authUser('abc@abc.com','abc123').then(function (result) {
console.log("Result of successful auth user is ");
console.log(result);
expect(result).toEqual(true);
done();
}, function (error) {
console.log("error of failure auth user is ",error);
expect(false).toBe(true);
done();
});
httpBackend.whenPOST('/oauth/token').passThrough();
$rootScope.$digest();
//httpBackend.flush();
});

});
```

It will be great if somebody have any solution for this to do real http call in karma test

Comment: During testing, we want our tests to run quickly and have no external dependencies so we don’t want to send XHR or JSONP requests to a real server. All we really need is to verify whether a certain request has been sent or not, or alternatively just let the application make requests, respond with pre-trained responses and assert that the end result is what we expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

When an Angular application needs some data from a server, it calls the $http service, which sends the request to a real server using $httpBackend service. With dependency injection, it is easy to inject $httpBackend mock (which has the same API as $httpBackend) and use it to verify the requests and respond with some testing data without sending a request to a real server.

Try and modify according to your data,

```
it('verify authenticating user',
function() {

httpBackend.expect('POST', '/oauth/token')
  .respond(200, "[{ success : 'true', id : 123 }]");

AuthService.authUser('abc@abc.com', 'abc123')
  .then(function(data) {
    expect(data.success).toBeTruthy();
});

$httpBackend.flush();
});
```